# Read a value multiple times or store as a variable first time round?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

Basically, is it better practice to store a value into a variable at the first run through, or to continually use the value?  The code will explain it better:

```
TextWriter tw = null;
if (!File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingFile"]))
{
   // ...
   tw = File.CreateText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingFile"]);
}
```

or

```
TextWriter tw = null;
string logFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingFile"].ToString();
if (!File.Exists(logFile))
{
    // ...
    tw = File.CreateText(logFile);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clarity is important, and DRY (don't repeat yourself) is important. This is a micro-abstraction - hiding a small, but still significant, piece of functionality behind a variable. The performance is negligible, but the positive impact of clarity can't be understated. Use a well-named variable to hold the value once it's been acquired.

Comment: To add to this, when you have a separate statement for assigning the value, it helps debugging in error scenarios. e.g. if the value of variable is invalid and causing error / exception, you can check it before using it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

the 2nd solution is better for me because :

- the dictionary lookup has a cost
- it's more readable

Or you can have a singleton object with it's private constructor that populates once all configuration data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Second one would be the best choice.

Imagine this next situation. Settings are updated by other threads and during some of them, since setting value isn't locked, changes to another value.

In the first situation, your execution can fail, or it'll be executed fine, but code was checking for a file of some name, and later saves whatever to a file that's not the one checked before. This is too bad, isn't it?

Another benefit is you're not retrieving the value twice. You get once, and you use wherever your code needs to read the whole setting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, the second one is more readable. But if you talk about performance - do not optimize on early stages and without profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I must agree with the others. Readability and DRY is important and the cost of the variable is very low considering that often you will have just Objects and not really store the thing multiple times.

There might be exceptions with special or large objects. You must keep in mind the question if the value you cache might change in between and if you would like or not (most times the second!) to know the new value within your code! In your example, think what might happen when ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingFile"] changes between the two calls (due to accessor logic or thread or always reading the value from a file from disk).

Resumee: About 99% you will want the second method / the cache!

Answer (score 0):

IMO that would depend on what you are trying to cache. Caching a setting from App.conig might not be as benefiial (apart from code readability) as caching the results of a web service call over a GPRS connection.